# ¿Es posible que simple_html_dom se actualice cada 24horas?

Tags: php

Es posible hacer que simple html se actualice cada 24 horas, o a las 00:00hs de todos los dias?
Tengo este codigo ya funcional:

```
<?php 
// if (is_string($spans_name2[10])) { b_match_status b_match_info-elem
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $contadores[0]; $i++) {
     $html =  file_get_html('https://miweb.net/');

    // $span=$html->find("span.name",0)->innertext;
    $spans_name2 = array();
    foreach($html->find('div.b_match_team') as $element) {
      array_push($spans_name2, $element->plaintext);
    }
    $final = array();
    foreach($html->find('div[class="b_match_status b_match_info-elem"]') as $element) {
      array_push($final, $element->plaintext);
    }

?>

<h5><?php echo date('H:i', $date[$i]).' -'.$spans_name2[$loc] .'vs'.  $spans_name2[$vis]; ?></h5>
```

Pero lo que pasa es que se cambia cada vez que entra, y esta web cambia `$date` y me queda mal, por ejemplo me pone la hora de abajo en la posicion uno, no se si me explico, igual **no hace falta que lo entiendan**, **solo necesito saber si se puede hacer que se actualice cada 24 horas**

Comment: se ve mi pregunta? Porque nada la ve?

Comment: Para ejecutar un script regularmente en un entorno gnu/linux, puedes usar cron.